# Updating Google Pay App Loyalty Card through API

Tags: android, google-pay

We have added Loyalty Card to Google Pay App using Android API.

**Link** - 
https://developers.google.com/pay/save/guides/loyalty/get-started-android

It works fine. From our App on clicking Save to Wallet we are able to see the saved Loyalty Card in Google Pay App.

Now we need to **update the added Loyalty card** through Android API. We checked through the API document, we  didn't find any reference to it.

**Is it possible to update the Loyalty Card and if yes how?**

Comment: Instructions to update loyalty points through API are provided here https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/loyalty/concepts

Comment: The link is not active anymore. Could add more details? How can I update loyalty points using android api? A quick answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Made any progress ever since?

Comment: I found this link, but actually I didn't get the loyalty card updated... https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/engage-through-google-pay

Answer (score 1):

For PHP

I create 2 extra methods in RestMethods.php that use the methods defined in Walletobjects.php

```
 public function updateLoyaltyClass($classId, $objectPayload){
    $response = NULL;
    $service = new Google_Service_Walletobjects($this->client);

    try {
        $response = $service->loyaltyclass->update($classId, $objectPayload);
        $response["code"] = 200;
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $gException)  {
        $response = $gException->getErrors();
        $response["code"] = $gException->getCode();
        echo("\n>>>> [START] Google Server Error response:");
        var_dump($response);
        echo("\n>>>> [END] Google Server Error response\n");
    } catch (Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }

return $response;

}


public function updateLoyaltyObject($objectId, $objectPayload){
    $response = NULL;
    $service = new Google_Service_Walletobjects($this->client);

    try {
        $response = $service->loyaltyobject->update($objectId, $objectPayload);
        $response["code"] = 200;
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $gException)  {
        $response = $gException->getErrors();
        $response["code"] = $gException->getCode();
        echo("\n>>>> [START] Google Server Error response:");
        var_dump($response);
        echo("\n>>>> [END] Google Server Error response\n");
    } catch (Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }

return $response;
}
```

Then created my own update.php which reuses the ResourceDefinitions.php class and objects, which you can edit inline with the documentation

```
<?php

require_once "Config.php"; // define constants
require_once 'RestMethods.php';
require_once "Services.php";
require_once 'Walletobjects.php';
require_once 'ResourceDefinitions.php';

$restMethods = RestMethods::getInstance();

$issuerUID = "Your Issuer ID";
$classUid = "Your Class ID";
$classId = sprintf("%s.%s" , $issuerUID, $classUid);
$objectUid= "Your Object ID"; 
$objectId = sprintf("%s.%s", $issuerUID, $objectUid);


//fetch object and class from resource
$objectResourcePayload = ResourceDefinitions::makeLoyaltyObjectResource($classId, $objectId);
$classResourcePayload = ResourceDefinitions::makeLoyaltyClassResource($classId);
//print_r($objectResourcePayload);
//print_r($classResourcePayload);

$classUpdateResponse = $restMethods->updateLoyaltyClass($classId,$classResourcePayload);
$objectUpdateResponse = $restMethods->updateLoyaltyObject($objectId,$objectResourcePayload);

print_r($classUpdateResponse);
print_r($objectUpdateResponse);



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit passes with with the Android API, recommend updating your solution to use the REST API. See note here https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-android-sdk for reference.